# Jquery getting id from inserted HTML snippet

Tags: jquery

I'm inserting a snippet of HTML through .get, and the new HTML when inserted (using .append) will have an `<li>` element with an id attribute I need. Any way of getting a reference to the last inserted element, and query from there, perhaps? Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(yourhtml).find('li:last').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the :nth-child selector.

```
$("li:nth-child(3)").attr('id'); //selects the third, as an example
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Isn't this provided I already know the id of the li element which is inserted?